# simple_form month translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, simple-form, rails-i18n

I am dealing with a Rails 4 application using simple_form. I want to display the app in spanish so I did `I18n.locale = :es`. Then I created the labels for simple_form in `simple_form.es.yml` and everything works all right except for the month dropdown in a birthday field (date attribute). I get this screen:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the labels are working right, but the select field kindly tries to say 'translation missing'. I don't know where to add my translation strings. Please help!

I already searched in simple_form documentation and a couple of other posts in SO but found nothing. I am a newbie in translation APIs.

Code behind is just:

```
<%= f.input :birthday, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year, 
    end_year: Date.today.year - 120, order: [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the locale configured in simple-form.[locale].yaml

Useful links:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/695#issuecomment-10495237

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml#L18-L21

Comment: i'll give it a try in a few days, this is blocking issue for my project but it is in development yet. I tried the locales but didn't got the way to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible problems according to my experiences.

1. because you have conflict key name in your YAML file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kIMr.png. Just remove the conflict key.
2. if step 1 it doesn't work add the following line to your en.yml file. and make sure that you don't has conflict key name in Yaml file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Url.png
3. The final step is go to your other [locale].yml. In this case I want to translate to "Khmer" language, so I will go to my "kh.yml" and paste this line of code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6I5s.png

If you follow my step carefully I guarantee it will working.

I hope this will help you.